Confused by excess of wires in light fitting (UK)
I want to swap out an old (damaged) ceiling rose for an LED fitting - however there are more wires than I was expecting coming in.
This is one of two lights connected to the same switch but there appears to be three lives coming in here? I'm guessing one of these goes to the second light but what would the third be for?


One from/for power, two to second light, and the third one for the switch.

And it would appear to this Yank that they used the terminals "wrong" per labeling (and have doubled up wires in what must be the switched live on the right side) where if they had used that for "live" as labeled, the "loop" terminals in the middle could handle the return from the switch loop, the brown to the light here and the red on to the next light without doubling up. But I'm not entirely up on old-school UK wiring practices, and I know there are folk who are that can answer this more definitively. The red/black color scheme says it's old-school.

@Ecnerwal the usage of the terminals is correct (and consistent into modern brown/blue wiring). The one marked "Line" (not "Live") is intended for the switched supply for the light. The "Loop" is intended (and used) to feed the incoming supply back out to the switch and on to other lights. It's kind of weird here because there is a second switched light fitting piggy-backed off this one (hence the doubled up terminal). Normally you would have one spare terminal in both "Loop" and "Neutral" that can be used to continue the lighting circuit on to e.g. in another room.

You haven't said what arrangement of lights and switches you have, so I guess from looking at it that you have two lights controlled by the same switch.
All the Earths are connected to each other, as expected.
You appear to have an incoming live (red) to the Loop terminal and a neutral (black) to the Neutral terminal.
A live (red) wire goes from the Loop terminal to the switch.  The switched live (black, but should have been sleeved red or brown) comes back to the Live terminal.
The switched live (red) and neutral (black) head off to the second lamp from the Live and Neutral terminals.
